# Catching errors from subprocess.Popen when piping stdout to next Popen stdin

Tags: process, subprocess, pipe, popen

I'm trying to 'chain' multiple Popen subprocesses, and catch any errors thrown by each command.
I'm using Python 3.7.

This is an example of some of the code I'm trying to use:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError

try:
    process_breakmulti = Popen(['vcfbreakmulti', vcf_file], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
    (out, err) = process_breakmulti.communicate()
    if process_breakmulti.returncode != 0:
        print(err, process_breakmulti.stderr)
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)

#use the stdout of process_breakmulti as stdin for process_allelicprimitives

try:
    process_allelicprimitives = Popen(['vcfallelicprimitives', '-kg'], stdin=process_breakmulti.stdout, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
    (out, err) = process_allelicprimitives.communicate()
    if process_allelicprimitives.returncode != 0:
        print(err, process_allelicprimitives.stderr)
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)
```

And this is the error that's thrown from the above code.

```
....
    process_allelicprimitives = Popen(['vcfallelicprimitives', '-kg'], stdin=process_breakmulti.stdout, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
  File "/hpc-home/ethering/anaconda3/envs/python37/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 753, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/hpc-home/ethering/anaconda3/envs/python37/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1376, in _get_handles
    p2cread = stdin.fileno()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I'm think I'm not using the communicate() method correctly, but not sure how to use is properly.

I'd really appreciate if someone could show me how to use this properly.